# Invert Colours of Transparent Image in Swift

Tags: swift, colors, imageview

Ive downloaded this picture with a transparent background and put it in an "Image View" in swift, just want to know if there is anyway possible to invert the image's outline to be white instead of black? My background is blue which is the reason it looks the way is does now. Much appreciate everyones help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What OS are you doing this for? iOS? macOS? Linux? tvOS? watchOS?

Comment: @rmaddy that’s ok, I was able to fix it now. Thanks for trying to help anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To invert the colors of the `image` property of an image view, use the following :

```
let startImage = CIImage(image: yourImageView.image!)

if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert") {
    filter.setValue(startImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage!)
    yourImageView.image = newImage
}
```

Answer (score 5):

when declaring your image use the following:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "name")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
yourImageView.image = image
yourImageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

This is the option you are looking for:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagerenderingmode/uiimagerenderingmodealwaystemplate?language=objc